# How to point to the Amazon EC2 instance's localhost?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I've an Amazon's EC2 instance up and running Ubuntu 12.04, I've installed LAMP. Apache is running, but how can I actually point to the default Document Root from the browser.

Comment: @Madbreaks and Smita I've figured that out by myself. I just had to edit **security group** and allow Port 80.

Comment: How did you edit the security group of ec2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put your instance's public IP address on the browser, if that's what you meant to ask. that will open up the default web root page of the server hosted at your ec2 instance.

Comment: Its showing Timeout everytime I try to map it using my Public IP.

Comment: it means, either you are trying to use your private IP or your apache is not running. If you see in your aws console you have dns domain something like `ec2-184-73-227-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com`. where 184.73.227.15 is your public IP address.

Comment: I've figured the problem its just a **security group** settings to allow port 80. BTW I've already checked `pgrep apache` to make sure that apache is running.

Comment: Yes you need to unblock port 80, I assumed it to open

Answer (score 2):

If you mean access the instance's localhost interface remotely using a standard browser and internet connection, you can't.

Comment: So how can I view its locahost?

Comment: Also if its not possible then how can I use PHPmyadmin? There should be a way out.